# JQuery Animate only works once

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Hi I am using JQuery to animate 2 div boxes on my page , This does work fine first time but subsequent times I just get visible boxes without any animation effects , The code is below which is triggered from a button called buttonx. Thanks for any help in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // lWhen document loaded 

$("#buttonx").click(function() { DisplayUniDiv( 40,250,300 ) }); 
$('#UniDivHead').click(function() { CloseDiv() }); 
    });



   function DisplayUniDiv(top,width,height,color) { 

dvHead = $('#UniDivHead') ; 
dvBody = $('#UniDivBody') ;     

    // Display the Div Head 
dvHead.css("visibility", "visible");
if (color) { color = "#" + color ; } else { color = "#0066cc"  } ;  
    dvHead.css("background", color ) ;
dvHead.css("top", top + 'px' ); 
dvHead.css("width", width + 'px') ;
    MarginLeft = (width / 2) ; 
    MarginLeft = "-" + MarginLeft ;     
dvHead.css("marginLeft", MarginLeft) 
dvHead.append("Close") ; 

    // Display the body 
dvBody.css("visibility", "visible");
dvBody.css("background", '#CCC' ) ;
    HeadHeight = dvHead.height() ; 
dvBody.css("top", top + HeadHeight + 'px' ); 
dvBody.css("width", width + 'px') ; 
dvBody.css("marginLeft", MarginLeft)    
dvBody.animate({height:height},500);

    }

    function CloseDiv() {
dvHead = $('#UniDivHead') ; 
dvBody = $('#UniDivBody') ;

dvHead.css("visibility", "hidden");
dvBody.css("visibility", "hidden"); 

     }
```

Comment: Can you include the HTML as well? It's really hard to imagine what this is trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because in `close` function, you just hide the element (here: `dvBody.css("visibility", "hidden");` ) , but you should set its height to 0. like:

```
dvBody.css({"visibility":"hidden", height:0});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be that the first time you execute DisplayUniDiv(), it actually manipulates the dimensions and other factors, as well as make the objects visible.

When you execute CloseDiv(), it makes the objects invisible.

When you execute DisplayUniDiv() the second time, it does make the objects visible, but all the other properties are already in the state that you try to animate them to. The animation still "runs" but it doesn't have anything to do.

If you want to have a visible 2nd animation, try to reset the remaining object properties besides only hiding them. That might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This part only works once:

```
if (color) { color = "#" + color ; } else { color = "#0066cc"  } ;  
    dvHead.css("background", color ) ;
```

As it will follow this sequence, which is invalid after the first iteration:

```
ABCDEF -> #ABCDEF -> ##ABCDEF -> ###...
```

I've condensed your code a little, so see if this works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#buttonx').click(function() {
    DisplayUniDiv(40, 250, 300)
  });

  $('#UniDivHead').click(function() {
    $('#UniDivHead, '#UniDivBody').hide();
  });
});



function DisplayUniDiv(top, width, height, color) {
  $('#UniDivHead').show();

  if (color.index('#') == -1) {
    color = '#' + color;
  } else {
    color = '#0066cc'
  };
  $('#UniDivHead').css('background', color);
  $('#UniDivHead').css('top', top);
  $('#UniDivHead, #UniDivBody').width(width);
  $('#UniDivHead').css('margin-left', MarginLeft)
  $('#UniDivHead').append('<span>Close</span>');

  $('#UniDivBody').show();
  $('#UniDivBody').css('background', '#CCC');
  $('#UniDivBody').css('top', top + $('#UniDivHead').height());
  $('#UniDivBody').css('margin-left', -(width / 2))
  $('#UniDivBody').animate({height: height}, 500);
}
```

Basically, when you were hiding your elements, setting `visibility: hidden;` doesn't do the trick most of the time. jQuery has `.hide()` which sets `display: none;`.